# Performance issue when user's home directory have large number of files

Tags: 18.04, files, filesystem, home-directory

I'm on Ubuntu for years (I format only root partition when I re-install or update) and now my home directory have many files from installs programs such as Nodejs,Android studio and bunch of other programs. All lies in a flat structure. Also it have bunch of hidden folders that generated by programs. Now my laptop is very slow at login and even when unlocking the screen. I have another account that I'm not using much and It works smoothly. What will be the solution to this problem? Do I need a re-structuring the file system or is that the real reason to slow down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories grow over time. If you add many files, the space needed to store the entries grows. This may in extreme cases, and yours may be such one, slow down file search and file access.

**Two steps** are needed to tackle your problem:

1. **Prune extraneous files and folders**. Pruning extraneous files will to a large extent remain a manual task. Although clean-up programs such as Janitor may help cleaning up extraneous files, it essentially will remain a manual task to inspect your hidden folders, see whether the corresponding application is still installed and used before deleting the hidden directory.
2. **Optimize the folders**.  In general, this can be achieved by copying the folders and delete the originals. However, file system tools may provide means to do this without having to re-copy the data. With the ext4 file system, the option -D will cause the file system to be optimized. If for example an ext4-formatted file system is referred to as /dev/sdb1, following command will check the file system and optimize it: `sudo e2fsck -D /dev/sdb1`. Note that a file system that you check cannot be in use.

Yet, it allegedly is better practice to start anew every few years, i.e., perform a full fresh install from time to time. This automatically will cause you to *safely* get rid of superfluous files and folders that accumulated over the years, and refresh your file system. To that aim, make sure your backup is up to date, then reinstall the system wiping everything out, then reinstall (only) the applications you effectively use and copy your data back into the new installation.